# How does the heteroskedasticity-robust SE equal the conservative estimator of SE for sample average treatment effect?

Tags: variance, regression-coefficients, causality, robust-standard-error

I have been told that the heteroskedasticity-robust standard error of $\hat{\beta}_1$ from an OLS regression with a binary $X_i$: $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u$ should be the same as the conservative estimator of the sample average treatment effect (SATE) SEs when treatment is randomly assigned (such as in a randomized controlled trial). Hence, $$ \hat{Var}(\hat{\beta}_1) = \frac{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})^2 \hat{u}^2_i}{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2} $$ which is the heteroskedasticity robust variance should then equal $$\hat{Var}(\tau{ATE}) = \frac{Var(Y_{1i})}{N_T} + \frac{Var(Y_{0i})}{N_C} $$, which is the conservative estimator of the sample average treatment effect variance with a randomly assigned treatment, with $N_T$ and $N_C$ being the number of treated units and the number of control units. Additionally, $Var(Y_{1i})$ and $Var(Y_{0i})$ are variances of the potential outcomes under treatment and control conditions which under the assumption of random assignment can be estimated using the sample variance of the observed outcome $Y_i$ in the treatment and control groups. I am able to show that when $X_i$ is a binary treatment indicator $\hat{Var(\beta_1)}$ is $$ \frac{\sum(x_i - p)^2 \hat{u}^2_i }{np(1-p)}$$ where $p$ is the proportion of treated: $N_T/N$, but not sure how to move forward.